# Ideal $I=\langle x^2+1 \rangle$ in $R=C[0,1]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be the ring all continous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $I$ be the ideal generated by $f(x)$ where $f(x)=x^2+1$ .Then

$(a) I$ is maximal ideal of $R$

$(b) I$ is prime ideal of $R$.

$(c) \frac RI $ is finite

$(d)char\frac RI$ is a prime number.

My attempt:-

For $(a)$

$I$ is not a maximal ideal since every maximal ideal of $R$ is of the form $\{f\in R: f(c)=0\}$, for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$, and the given polynomial doesn't vanish anywhere.

But I have one question here: $R$ is a ring with identity ,namely $f(x)=1, \forall x\in [0,1]$, so every proper ideal is contained in a maximal ideal.

But how can a non-vanishing function be in the set of functions vanishing at a particular point?[or if the question is simply put , in which maximal ideal is $I$ contained?]

For $(c)$

We have $\{ax+b+\langle x^2+1\rangle : a,b \in \mathbb{R}\}\subset\frac RI$   thus $\frac RI$ is not finite.

I have no idea about other options

Am I thinking properly? Please help me clear my doubts and answer rest of the parts.

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Isn't the function $x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{x^2 + 1}$ an inverse of the generator? So, $I = R$?

Comment: Ah! yes , I see no problem with that

Comment: Then $I$ is not maximal and prime ideal since it is not proper , $\frac RI$ is isomorphic to the trivial ring $\{0\}$ , so $(c)$ is true and $char \frac  RI=1$ is non-prime. Please confirm.

Comment: That is correct. I have updated my answer to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have $I = R$ since the generator is invertible with inverse $x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$.

(a) Your observation that it not a maximal ideal was correct. However, in this case, the reason is that it is not even a proper ideal!
This is precisely why you struggled with the last part of the doubt. As you noted, every *proper ideal* is part of a maximal ideal.

(c) We clearly know that $R/I$ is finite now. The error in your reasoning is that you were probably thinking that you are in the polynomial ring.
In that case, $$ax + b + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle \neq a'x + b' + \langle x^2 + 1\rangle$$ iff $(a, b) \neq (a', b')$.

However, here you don't have that anymore.

(b) and (d) should be answered now based on the knowledge that $I = R$.

But just for completeness -
(b) $I$ is not prime since it is not proper.
(d) ${\rm char}\ R/I = 1$, not a prime.

Comment: Yes !! Thanks a lot .

Comment: You are welcome. :)